# Parsing a HTML timetable using Jsoup

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I understand that there are quite a few questions out there about parsing a HTML table. However, after doing some research and looking into Jsoup I'm a little stumped by it.

I have a timetable

[image]

I want to parse to take out the text of the `<td>` tags, but keeping it in some sort of format.

By just messing around with Jsoup trying out the avaliable functions and looking at the Cookbook and the current API documentation. From this I have managed to do the following;

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://crwnmis3.staffs.ac.uk/Reporting/Individual;Student%20Sets;name;L2SE?&template=Online%20One%20Page%20Student%20Set&days=1-5&periods=5-53&width=0&height=0").get();

String title = doc.select("td").text();      
System.out.println(title);
```

The only issue is this prints out one long string.

I'd much rather have the data split up into manageable chunks. Maybe I could do a `title.Split();`?
However, that would mean no lecture has a time. Unless there is away of counting white spaces and doing a count for the time, assuming each white space is 15 minutes.

Comment: Instead of just playing around, read JSoup's documentation and work with the document tree properly.

Comment: I'd first get the column of the table (time), and then get the actual cell in that column, (actual data). Then you'd have the time and the actual data.

Comment: You may need to fetch `tr`s first and your first tr will give you the number of columns and each will separated by 15 mins.. You need to play with that number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would start by processing a row at each time. so i would start by getting the quarters of hour after each weekday, using a selector like

```
tr td.row-label-one:contains(Tue) ~ td
```

If you loop the contents of an array like ["Mon","Tue",..."Fri"] you can process the all week.

This css query will give you the td element siblings in that weekday.
and those siblings are the quarters of hour in that weekday.

So just use 9am as you base and count until you find a non empty element
like "COSE50582/Lec/Sem2 Object-Oriented Application Engineering Gillibrand D, Mansfield GD D116"

You can find this element at index 4, so 9 + (15 min * 4 ) = 10 am

Note: For simplicity sake im assuming all subjects only have 4 quarters in duration otherwise you could use the colspan to calculate the subjects duration.

Comment: Perfect. Had to use logic to get the lecture times at the correct times and so on. However, the selector was just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You are selecting all elements that match "td" and printing one big string of it. You can get them as a collection of elements and iterate over them one by one like this:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://crwnmis3.staffs.ac.uk/Reporting/Individual;Student%20Sets;name;L2SE?&template=Online%20One%20Page%20Student%20Set&days=1-5&periods=5-53&width=0&height=0").get();
Elements titles = doc.getElementsByTag("td");      
for(Element e : titles) {
    System.out.println(e.text());
}
```